# How to make google play filter my app for tablets

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-screen-support

I have an app and I want to upload it on google play. But the only thing I want is to disable it for tablets, I mean what I need to write in manifest, that google play could filter my app for tablets in search results. E.g when we wrote `<uses-feature>` camera in our `manifest`, google play  shows our app only on devices, that has camera feature. So the similar thing I want is not to show my app for tablets. So what I can write in manifest file, that google doesn't show my app in search results on tablets.

I've tried something like this, but when I uploaded it to google play, in available devices section I saw, that my app is available for tablets too.

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:largestWidthLimitDp="600"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Comment: Try to remove largestWidthLimitDp because it does not work if value is greater than 320 mentioned in the link below
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element#largestWidth

Comment: Ok thanks, but how can I test it without reuploading to play store? E.g. if I will run the app from studio, it will launch successfully on tablets.